# PHP 7.1 on hosted server not recognizing session.save_path

Tags: php, session-variables

I am pulling my hair out over this issue.  It seems simple enough, but the following simple script is not working for me.  I want to keep my session files in the directory as indicated.  I have the 'musanizer_session_tmp' folder in the same root with this php script:

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['testit'])) {
    ini_set ('session.auto_start' , '1' );
    ini_set('session.save_path', '../musanizer_session_tmp');
    $_SESSION['tester'] = 'Testing Session Save Path! ';
    echo '<script language="Javascript">';
    echo 'window.location.href="sesstest.php?testit=YES"';
    echo '</script>';
}   
else   
{
    echo "===>>> ". $_SESSION['tester'].date('H:i:s');
}
```

Isn't that fairly straightforward and correct?

Comment: OOps ... forgot to add that the sample code shown does not return the $_SESSION['tester'] value ... appears no session variable is being saved

Comment: `ini_set()` only lasts for the current script execution, so when you don't reference these in the second page, these settings aren't there.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I overlooked it on the test script.  However, correcting that makes no difference ... still getting a null value returned.  Also, I am watching the named storage folder for the existence of a session file.  The first part of that example should have created a session file, but did not.  That is the issue. Thanks. FrankMc

Comment: @FrankMcLeod Are you calling `session_start()` anywhere?

Comment: I would really suggest you not give a *relative* path to a global variable (session.save_path). Try something like `__DIR__.'/../musanizer_session_tmp'`.That would however be located in the *parent directory* of the directory the script is in. so probably only `__DIR__.'/musanizer_session_tmp'`

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I am now using the host's $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] and it gives me the exact path for the server to my session storage folder.  I might add that I have a localhost php 7.1 installation and I am getting the exact same problem on localhost.  I have culled down my sample script to     ini_set ('session.auto_start' , '1' );
    $mysavepath = 
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Musanizer4/musanizer_session_tmp/';
    ini_set('session.save_path', $mysavepath);
    $_SESSION['tester'] = 'Testing Session Save Path! ';

Comment: I am not using session_start() anywhere.  I thought the PHP 7.1 preferred method is ini_set ('session.auto_start' , '1' );  ... that was in my example script